# Material UI TextField select value not updating in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, recoiljs

I am building a form in a React component that allows users to edit student information. I am using Material-UI's `TextField` and `Select` components to create a dropdown menu for selecting a student's gender.

The issue I'm facing is that the `selectedOption` state variable, which is used to keep track of the currently selected gender option, is not being updated properly. When logging the value of `selectedOption`, it always appears to be empty.

Here is my code:

```
const EditStudentForm = () => {
    // Use
    const [currentStudent, setCurrentStudent] = useState<Student>({
        id: -1,
        name: '',
        email: '',
        gender: ''
    });

    const studentById = useRecoilValue(studentByIdState);
    const formState = useRecoilValue(editStudentFormState);

    // Gender Select
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState<string>('');

    useEffect(() => {
        if (formState) {
            setCurrentStudent(studentById);
            setSelectedOption(currentStudent.gender);
        }
    }, [studentById, currentStudent]);



    const handleOptionChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
        setSelectedOption(event.target.value as string);
    }

    const selectProps: SelectProps = {
        MenuProps: {
            anchorOrigin: {
                vertical: "bottom",
                horizontal: "left"
            },
            transformOrigin: {
                vertical: "top",
                horizontal: "left"
            }
        }
    };


    return (
        <>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Box
                sx={{ width: 320 }}
                role="user-form"
            >
                <Typography variant="h4" color="initial" sx={{ mt: 3, textAlign: 'center' }}>Edit student</Typography>
                <form>
                    <Stack sx={{ m: 2 }} spacing={2}>
                        <TextField
                            id="studentName"
                            label="Student name"
                            value={currentStudent.name}
                            variant='outlined'
                            focused={true}
                        //   onChange={}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            id="studentEmail"
                            label="Student email"
                            value={currentStudent.email}
                            variant='outlined'
                        //   onChange={}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            id="studentGender"
                            label="Student Gender"
                            defaultValue={''} // to avoid MUI: You have provided an out-of-range value
                            value={selectedOption}
                            onChange={handleOptionChange}
                            select
                            SelectProps={selectProps}
                            variant='outlined'
                        >
                            <MenuItem key={1} value={'male'}>
                                Male
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem key={2} value={'female'}>
                                Female
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem key={3} value={'other'}>
                                Other
                            </MenuItem>
                        </TextField>
                        <Stack direction="row" spacing={2} sx={{ justifyContent: 'end' }}>
                            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary">
                                Reset
                            </Button>
                            <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                                Add
                            </Button>
                        </Stack>
                    </Stack>
                </form>
            </Box>
        </>
    )
}

export default EditStudentForm;
```

with code provided above I get from as:

[image: form image showing TextField Select as empty]

I have tried many solutions from SO, but none has worked.
What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you forgot to add handleChange to TextFields